# Shiny not displaying ggplot data

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am new to working with shiny package. I am trying to use it to display a ggplot2 graph. I get no errors with my code, however data points are not appearing on the graph. When I select the variables from ui, the axes labels changes accordingly but the data is not added to the plot.

Thank you,

Code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
     sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(
             selectInput(inputId = "y", 
                         label = "Y-axis:", 
                         choices = c("P-value", "P-adjust"),
                         selected = "P-adjust"),
             selectInput(inputId = "x" , 
                         label = "X-axis:", 
                         choices = c("FC", "Mean_Count_PD"),
                         selected = "FC")
                 ),
         mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot"))
         ))

server <- function(input, output) 
     {
     output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
     ggplot(data = mir, aes(input$x,input$y)) + geom_point()
     })
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have to tell ggplot that your `input`s are names of variables in your dataset. This could be achieved e.g. by making use of the `.data` pronoun, i.e. instead of using `input$x` which is simply a string use `.data[[input$x]]` which tells ggplot that by `input$x` you mean the variable with that name in your data:

As you provided no data I could not check but this should give you the desired result:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "y", 
                  label = "Y-axis:", 
                  choices = c("P-value", "P-adjust"),
                  selected = "P-adjust"),
      selectInput(inputId = "x" , 
                  label = "X-axis:", 
                  choices = c("FC", "Mean_Count_PD"),
                  selected = "FC")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot"))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = mir, aes(.data[[input$x]], .data[[input$y]])) + geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Another way of making it work was to pass aes_string() to ggplot instead of aes().