# R shiny reactive x axis ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Say I have two different datasets with sales by age or region. Based on them, I can prepare bar charts as follows:

```
age <- data.frame("year" = c(2019, 2020), "age" = c("<30", "30-40", ">40"), "sales" = c(100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350)) 

geo <- data.frame("year" = c(2019, 2020), "geo" = c("Europe", "Asia", "America"), "sales" = c(70, 120, 170, 220, 270, 320)) 



ggplot(age, aes(fill=as.factor(year), x=age, y=sales))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity")

ggplot(geo, aes(fill=as.factor(year), x=geo, y=sales))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity")
```

Now, I want to use them in the reactive Shiny dashboard, where user can choose the dataset to plot. I try the following code:

```
# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Input:  ----
      selectInput("indicator", "Choose dataset",
                  c("age", "geo")),
      
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      plotOutput("plot1")
      
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    if (input$Indicator == "age"){
      ds1 <-age
    }
    else if (input$Indicator == "geo"){
      ds1 <-geo
    }
    return(ds1)
  })
  
  
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
      ggplot(datasetInput(), aes(fill=as.factor(year), x=input$indicator, y=sales))+
      geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity")
    
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But I get a blank dashboard, nothing happens. What is wrong with the code ?

Comment: Try with `x=.data[[input$indicator]]`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64620046/shiny-not-displaying-ggplot-data/64620568#64620568

Comment: @stefan Thanks, but I still get the same blank dashboard

Comment: ... besides that it should be `plotOutput("plot")` not `plot1`. Additionally it should be `if (input$indicator == ..` not `Indicator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two mistakes, both of which have been, already, pointed out by @stefan. This answer is just verbose implementation of what @stefan has already said. Nothing new.

1. input$Indicator and input$indicator are two different things. R is case-sensitive. Keep it either indicator at all places or Indicator at all places. Do not mix. In this answer I kept indicator at all places.
2. Output ID in the mainPanel(plotOutput()) is "plot1" chosen by you. HTML ID generated is plot1. However downstream in server you are referring output$plot ..."plot" id does not exist so it can not attach the output to correct element in the HTML. Again keep plot1 at both places or plot at both places. In this answer I kept plot1 at both the places.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
age <- data.frame("year" = c(2019, 2020), "age" = c("<30", "30-40", ">40"), "sales" = c(100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350)) 
geo <- data.frame("year" = c(2019, 2020), "geo" = c("Europe", "Asia", "America"), "sales" = c(70, 120, 170, 220, 270, 320)) 
# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Input:  ----
      selectInput("indicator", "Choose dataset",
                  choices = c("age", "geo"))),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      plotOutput("plot1")
      
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    if (input$indicator == "age"){
      ds1 <-age
    }
    else if (input$indicator == "geo"){
      ds1 <-geo
    }
    return(ds1)
  })
  
  
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ 
    ggplot(datasetInput(), aes(fill=as.factor(year), x=input$indicator, y=sales))+
      geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity")
    
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]